# Custom action filter in Yii2 does not work when request is POST and user is not authenticated

Tags: php, filter, yii2

So, I have my little Yii2 application with quizzes. Each `quiz` belongs to one `user`, `user` has many `quizzes`, standard thing. What I wanted to do is restrict users to update or delete quizzes that don't belong to them. Plain and simple.

Now, I realize, that there is specific solution for this kind of things called [RBAC](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#role-based-access-control-rbac), but I still didn't want to deal with roles and setting up all the things.

So I decided to create a little custom filter in order to do this.

```
namespace frontend\components;
use ...

class UserOwnerAccessControlFilter extends ActionFilter
{

public function beforeAction($action)
{
    if (Yii::$app->getUser()->isGuest) {
        return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(['site/login']);
    }
    $user = Yii::$app->getUser()->identity;
    $controllerID = $action->controller->id;
    if ($controllerID == 'quiz') {
        $quiz = Quiz::findOne(['id'=> Yii::$app->getRequest()->queryParams['id']]);
        if ($quiz->user_id != $user->id) {
            throw new ForbiddenHttpException(Yii::t('yii', 'You are not allowed to perform this action.'));
            return false;
        }
    } elseif ($controllerID == 'chapter') {
        //TODO
    }
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}

public function afterAction($action, $result)
{
    return parent::afterAction($action, $result);
}
}
```

And, of course, I inserted some lines to behaviors of `quiz` controller as well:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        ...
        [
            'class' => UserOwnerAccessControlFilter::className(),
            'only' => ['update', 'delete'],
        ]
    ];
}
```

As you can see from above this filter only applies to `update` and `delete` actions.

Now, I having tested all of this really, **really thoroughly**, I received result:

1. When I create a `quiz` with user `A`, login with user `B` and try to either edit or delete the `quiz`, filter works perfectly normal. I get `ForbiddenHttpException` exactly how I suppose to.
2. When I create a `quiz` with user `A`, logout, and try to reach `quiz/update` page(which uses `GET` http request) for the `quiz` unauthenticated, I get redirected to `site/login`. Exactly as I suppose to.
3. Now when I create a `quiz` with user `A`, logout, and being unauthenticated, **hack my way through** and make `POST` request for either `update` or `delete` action, **FILTER DOES NOT WORK!!!1** and request comes through.

Now, I'm new to PHP and Yii(and yes, I'm already hating it), so just in case, here's my `urlManager` code, maybe it has something to do with this:

```
...
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => 'true',
        'showScriptName' => 'false',
        'enableStrictParsing' => 'true',
        'scriptUrl' => '',
        'rules' => [
            '' => 'site/index',
            'about' => 'site/about',
            'contact' => 'site/contact',
            'logout' => 'site/logout',
            'signup' => 'site/signup',
            'login' => 'site/login',
            'request-password-reset' => 'site/request-password-reset',
            'quizzes' => 'quiz/index',
            'quizzes/create' => 'quiz/create',
            'quiz/<id:\d+>' => 'quiz/view',
            'quiz/<id:\d+>/edit' => 'quiz/update',
            'quiz/<id:\d+>/delete' => 'quiz/delete',
        ]
    ],
...
```

Can someone have any ideas about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Weird problem... maybe try a var_dump($user); just after the identity is fetched?

Comment: I've tried, the problem is when the request is POST, filter code is not even being executed, it just ignores the whole filter thing. That is it doesn't matter whether I'm gonna make var_damp or not, it ignores the filter like it's not even there.

Comment: Are you using REST? I guess your POST request is processed through an other controller than the one your filters are in...

Comment: Is it even possible? Given that `enableStrictParsing` is `true` and all the rules forbid request to be processed by anywhere elsewhere.